# Apache CXF trunk build error: Provider com.sun.tools.xjc.addon.apache_cxf.ts.ToStringPlugin not found

Tags: apache, maven, cxf

Just wondering how I can fix following error when trying to build Apache CXF from trunk:

```
    **Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin: Provider com.sun.tools.xjc.addon.apache_cxf.ts.ToStringPlugin not found**
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:214)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:164)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:348)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:428)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.findServices(Options.java:924)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.getAllPlugins(Options.java:357)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.AbstractExtensionBindingChecker.<init>(AbstractExtensionBindingChecker.java:94)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.ExtensionBindingChecker.<init>(ExtensionBindingChecker.java:77)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader$XMLSchemaParser.parse(ModelLoader.java:257)
        at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.NGCCRuntimeEx.parseEntity(NGCCRuntimeEx.java:337)
        at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContex

t.parse(ParserContext.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser.ParserContext.<init>(ParserContext.java:96)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.parser.XSOMParser.<init>(XSOMParser.java:125)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOMParser(ModelLoader.java:420)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOMParser(ModelLoader.java:428)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.createXSOM(ModelLoader.java:509)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:375)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:167)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:113)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:313)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractXSDToJavaMojo.execute(AbstractXSDToJavaMojo.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.XSDToJavaMojo.execute(XSDToJavaMojo.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've encountered something similar when building cxf project with JDK6. Take a look [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) for info about the codegen stuff and how to build.

Comment: thanks a lot Peter, i believe you have directed me in right direction. i just have found another link addressing similar issue [here](http://www.mindbug.org/2009/02/adding-endorsements-to-mavens-plugins.html) i'm still looking into this issue, i'll get back to you shortly on this.